# VB would not accept these text string characters

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, literals

I am trying to find this text string inside a rich text box and delete it,

```
Dim String1 As String = "<?xml version= "1.0"  encoding =" UTF-16"?>"
```

However, I keep receiving an "End of statement expected error".

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to escape your double quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Well how about I provide the answer, since I provided the answer :)

Escape your double quotes:

`"<?xml version= ""1.0""  encoding ="" UTF-16""?>"`

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [MSDN documentation on VB.NET string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711651%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
Within a string, a sequence of two double-quote characters is an escape sequence
representing a double quote in the string.
```

Therefore, you need to escape every double quotes within your `String` literal by adding yet another double quote char in front of it, like this:

```
Dim String1 As String = "<?xml version= ""1.0""  encoding ="" UTF-16""?>"
```

Comment: @WilfredoSalinas you are welcome. I suggest you accept David Zemens's post as the answer because he really was first to tip you in (in comments).